# how to delcare different types of constants in one enum class in java

Tags: java

I am trying to use enum class insted of interface with constants declared in it.

Actual:

```
public interface MyConstants {

public static final String MY_DATE_FORMAT ="mm/dd/yy";
public static final int BATCH_SIZE=500;

}
```

I am trying in the following way.

```
public enum MyConstants {
    MY_DATE_FORMAT("sdes");
    BATCH_SIZE(3);

    MyConstants(String ds){
    }

    MyConstants(int st){
    }

}
```

But I am getting syntax error at "`BATCH_SIZE(3);`" . Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an interface for constants is an anti-design pattern, and should be avoided.

3 is an `int`, and the constructor parameter requires a `String`. Pass in `Integer.toString(3)` instead. Why not use a final class with a private constructor?

Also, as mentioned before, you must separate enums using `,` then specify you are done declaring enums by putting `;` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer, I have read that after JDK 1.5, it is best practice to use enum instead of interface or classes. Which is better to use in my case?

Comment: Where did you read that? enums have better protection against reflection attacks, but at what cost? You're allocating an extra object for each constant you have. Then the overhead of actually accessing that constant through the enum; its a mess. Personally, I think you'd be better off using a final class with a private constructor. Mind linking me to where you read about using enums for constants?

Comment: While I'm on the subject of enums being bad for constants, how are you gonna ensure type safety? You can only accept things as a `String` right now. Unless you made more constructors and variables, you can only use `String`. This means that you'd have to manually parse the `String` back into whatever it actually was (`int` for example). I say its just not worth the reflection safety, which I highly doubt you need in this case

Comment: I don't need safety in my case. I am going with final class with private constructor approach. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate them by , instead of ;

```
public enum MyConstants {
    MY_DATE_FORMAT("sdes"), BATCH_SIZE(3);

    MyConstants(String ds) {
    }

    MyConstants(int st) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should read:

```
public enum MyConstantsEnum
{

    MY_DATE_FORMAT("sdes"), BATCH_SIZE(3);

    MyConstantsEnum(final String value)
    {
       // do something
    }

    MyConstantsEnum(final int value)
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Note the comma after MY_DATE_FORMAT and not the semi-colon that you have.

That said, this design will likely create significant issues downstream.

Comment: You mean, use public static final constant variables either in interface or class instead of this enum class in my case

Comment: Yes, it seems you are forcing the ENUM construct into a Constants use case and as @Vince points out, its an anti-pattern, which means it will most likely cause challenges.